# Minimal Hybrid migration office 365 MX record

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline, office365

We have preformed a minimal hybrid migration.

Migrated a few test mailboxes.

We have a few 100 to go.

> At this point can we change our MX record to Office 365?

Or, can we only do this at the end?

Answer (score 1):

> At this point can we change our MX record to Office 365?

Based on your other question, you probably want to wait until all of your mailboxes have been migrated to O365. Assuming that your current MX record points to your on premises Exchange server or to your 3rd party spam filter, which in turns delivers email to your on premises Exchange server, you'll probably want to keep that in place so that email for migrated and non-migrated mailboxes flows through your on premises Exchange server and 3rd party spam filter.

Once all mailboxes have been migrated you can change the MX record if it currently points to your on premises Exchange server. If your current MX record points to your 3rd party spam filter then you'll likely only need to change the destination that the 3rd party spam filter delivers email to.

Answer (score 0):

According your other thread, you could keep your MX record pointing to spam filter. The MX record could point to Exchange on-premise/O365, it all depends on your need.